# Is the written language of the Engineers actually translatable?

Tags: prometheus, alien-covenant

Did Ridley Scott intend the written language of the Engineers in *Prometheus* and *Alien: Covenant* to be translatable?

I think many, many mysteries can be uncovered - if those writings on the doors, walls, sleeping pods etc. were to be translated. I saw some forum posts where people tried to translate it, without much luck. But maybe over the years someone did it?

Comment: [See this](https://www.alien-covenant.com/topic/47806)

Comment: I realize you asked about writing, but on a related topic, here is translation of Prometheus's deleted engineer dialogue, which answers a lot of questions about the plot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFjTxnb2l04